# Subsets of n users with r relationships between them

Tags: r, dataframe, unique

**What I want**

I have a daframe whose first two columns are combinations of *m* string values. Those values are users ids and the dataframe represents relationships between them. Every row includes a user par (*user1*, *user2*) and the number of times *user1* has visited *user2*'s profile. There are *m* different users but there are no rows for every possible relationship, only for those who have visited the other's profile. Mutual pairs can have different values or even don't exist (if *user1* has visited *user2*'s profile but not the other way round).

I want to create reduced versions of my dataframe, easier to work with. As a result I want to extract groups of *n* users (*n* < *m*) with at least *r* relationships between. I need to develop a function that checks if there are at least *r* rows (relationships), combination of any group of *n* users (*n* < *m*). If so, the function returns a dataframe formed by them.
That is to say, the function should return a daframe (let's name it *S*) that meets the following requirements:

- *S*  is a subset of the original dataframe
- NROW(S) >= r
- NROW(unique(append(S[1],S[2]))) = n

**Small example**

This is a minimal example, where users ids are just one letter. There are 5 different users (a,b,c,d,e) and 10 relationships between them:

```
 >df
      user1   user2 views
 1        a       b     1
 2        a       c     1
 3        a       d     3
 4        b       a     1
 5        c       b     1
 6        c       d     2
 7        c       e     4
 8        d       a     5
 9        d       e     1
 10       d       c     2
```

For *r* = 8 *n* = 4, I try to extract a group of 4 users with at least 8 relationships between them. The output should be a dataframe of 8 rows that contain only 4 different *user* values in the first two columns (if any). There are 5 different 4-users combinations with the values above [(a,b,c,d) ,(a,b,c,e), (a,b,d,e), (a,c,d,e), (b,c,d,e)]. However only of one of them (a,b,c,d) includes 8 relationships between members. Output should be:

```
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
    user1   user2 views
1       a       b     1
2       a       c     1
3       a       d     3
4       b       a     1
5       c       b     1
6       c       d     2
7       d       a     5
8       d       c     2
```

For *r* = 6 *n* = 4, the aim is to find a group of 4 users with 6 relationships between them. In this case there are 2 4-users combinations that meet the requirement of forming at least 6 rows [(a,b,c,d), (a,c,d,e)]. Output could be any of those:

```
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
    user1   user2 views
1       a       b     1
2       a       c     1
3       a       d     3
4       b       a     1
5       c       b     1
6       c       d     2
7       d       a     5
8       d       c     2

 [1] "a" "c" "d" "e"
    user1   user2 views
1       a       c     1
2       a       d     3
3       c       d     2
4       c       e     4
5       d       a     5
6       d       c     2
7       d       e     1
```

For *r* > 8, no 4-users combination is valid. There are no 4-users group with more than 8 relationships between them. Then, output should be `NULL`.

**Solution (if dataframe was small)**

A solutions for a small dataframe (that works for this minimal example) could be to get all possible combinations of n-users and iterate over them, checking if one of them meets the requirement of forming r relationships in df. Code could be something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(trotter)

obtainUserGroup <- function(df,n,r){

## Get unique letter _users_ in dataframe
us <- unique(append(df$user1,df$user2))

## All possible combinations of users in _us_ in groups of _n_ users
users <- cpv(n,us)

## Iterate over any possible group of _n_ users
for(i in 1:NROW(users)){


    l <- as.character(users[i])
    l <- as.data.frame(permutations(n,2,l),stringAsFactors=FALSE)
    names(l) <- c("user1","user2")

    # Check which combinations in l are part of df
    dc <- semi_join(df,l,by = c("user1", "user2"))


    if(NROW(dc) >= r) return(dc)

 }

return(NULL)
}

df <- data.frame(c("a","a","a","b","c","c","c","d","d","d"), c("b","c","d","a","b","d","e","a","e","c"), c(1,1,3,1,1,2,4,5,1,2), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
names(df) <- c("user1","user2","views")
n <- 4
r <- 8

obtainUserGroup(df,n,r)
```

**Problem**

My user dataframe is quite large. Trying to reduce a dataframe including thousand of users (*m* > 7000) users to one much smaller of just a hundred or a few hundreds (*n* << *m*) is troublesome. Iterating over the number of possible combinations is not feasible.

Is it possible to check all combinations in a different (much faster) way than the for-loop?
Is there any other way to approach this problem, different than checking all possible combinations?

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand the question. Your code example is not reproducible (what is cpv()? what is semi_join()?) However something tells me, the answer might partly be, not to iterate over all possible combinations of two letters but over the combinations of two letters that actually appear in your dataset.

Comment: @Bernhard I am sorry I did not include the libraries I am using.  I have updated my question to include them. [cpv(n,lett)](https://github.com/ram6ler/trotter/blob/master/README.md) gets all possible combinations of values in _lett_ in groups of _n_. [Semi_join(df,l)](http://www.inside-r.org/node/230646) returns rows in _df_ that match rows in _l_ .

Comment: @Bernhard I am considering your suggestion about iterating over the combinations that are actually in my dataset. However, I do not know how to identify them without iterating over all possible combinations.

Comment: letter1 = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "d");

letter2 = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "c", "d");

strsplit(unique(paste(letter1, letter2))," ")

paste the letter1 and letter2 together, to get one string per combination. Than you can use unique() to find each combination only once. If it helps, you can split the letters again using strsplit but it depends on further use, if that is necessary. An alternative Approach could be the use of table() as in table(letter1,letter2) but that probably gets more complicated later on.

Comment: @Bernhard If I get this right, your comment suggest a method to identify rows that have duplicate values in columns _letter1_  and _letter2_ . However, this is not necessary because there are not such duplicates. There are not 2 rows whose values in _letter1_ and _letter2_ are the same. Possible combinations I iterate over are composed of _n_ values, where n > 2 and therefore those combinations cannot be directly compared with the actual rows' content, as they include more elements.

Comment: I am sorry, obviously the one thing I was write with is, that I still have not understood the question. Maybe you have more luck with others.

Comment: @Bernhard Thank you for trying! I understand the requirements are complex.  May you suggest which points I need to elaborate further or more clearly?I will try to add a user case to make sense to the data, in case it makes it easier to follow my explanations.